# Looping in selenium

Tags: selenium

I recorded one script using Selenium IDE which contain clicking on a link and now i want to add loop to run same script multiple time, for this i am converting script to python but unable to add loop.Please help me in this regards.

Answer (score 2):

Heres some text direct from selenium docs:

> Data Driven Testing: 
>   Data Driven Testing refers to using the same test (or tests) multiple times with varying data. These data sets are often from external files i.e. .csv file, text file, or perhaps loaded from a database. Data driven testing is a commonly used test automation technique used to validate an application against many varying input. When the test is designed for varying data, the input data can expand, essentially creating additional tests, without requiring changes to the test code.

```
# Collection of String values
source = open("input_file.txt", "r")
values = source.readlines()
source.close()
# Execute For loop for each String in the values array
for search in values:
    sel.open("/")
    sel.type("q", search)
    sel.click("btnG")
    sel.waitForPageToLoad("30000")
    self.failUnless(sel.is_text_present("Results * for " + search))
```

Hope it helps. More info at: [Selenium Documentation](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/06_test_design_considerations.html#data-driven-testing)

Best Regards,

Paulo Bueno.

Answer (score 0):

Try a loop similar to this example using "for x in range (0,5):" to set the number of times you wish it to iterate.

```
    def test_py2webdriverselenium(self):
        for x in range(0,5):
            driver = self.driver
            driver.get("http://www.bing.com/")
            driver.find_element_by_id("sb_form_q").click()
            driver.find_element_by_id("sb_form_q").clear()
            driver.find_element_by_id("sb_form_q").send_keys("testing software")
            driver.find_element_by_id("sb_form_go").click()
            driver.find_element_by_link_text("Bing").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this for some situations that I have little information:

```
list = [''' list containing all items ''']
index = 0
while True:
    try:
        # do what you want with list[index]
        index += 1
    except:
        # index exception occured 
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

In java you can do this as below:

```
# import packages or classes

public class testClassName(){

before test Methods(){
}

@Test
public void testMethod(){
    for(int i =0, i<=5, i++){
        WebElement element = driver.findElementById("link_ID");
        element.click();
        waitForPageLoaded(5);
    }
}

after Test Method(){
}
}
```